geojson lat lon polygon draw smaller inner polygon
I need to write a function that takes a GeoJSON based on lat and lon values and draws polygon to 2d canvas.
In addition to that I need to add some distance and draw inner polygon where 4 sides (north,east,west,south) of the polygon will have different distances from outer polygon. I have a problem with edge coordinates being output in one dimension only, where somehow when drawing a polygon some of the point/lines need to be offset by a single side either north or south etc... or in some cases 2 sides need to be taken into account.
Can anyone point me in the direction of the solution? So far most of the lines are drawn correctly, except for the edge cases in the green circles.
Not correct

The correct image should be like this
Correct

The codepen of current implementation
https://codepen.io/Zlatko-Memisevic/pen/qBGNVgj


const exampleGeoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [9.409277330768161, 47.330294996637527],
          [9.40929555711242, 47.330394995087424],
          [9.409449188016863, 47.330385694636568],
          [9.409441872135783, 47.330340644668418],
          [9.409432145964761, 47.330341377653177],
          [9.409430621953572, 47.330332010609965],
          [9.409383287787568, 47.330335311475089],
          [9.409376169945089, 47.330288098791449],
          [9.409349057871147, 47.330289992509627],
          [9.409347814140572, 47.330283553765319],
          [9.409279252163072, 47.330288260899749],
          [9.409281541354549, 47.330294699779891],
          [9.409277330768161, 47.330294996637527]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
};

function drawGeoJsonOnCanvas(geoJson, canvasId, offsets) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (!canvas) {
    console.error(`Canvas element with id "${canvasId}" not found.`);
    return;
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const bbox = turf.bbox(geoJson);
  const scaleX = canvas.width / (bbox[2] - bbox[0]);
  const scaleY = canvas.height / (bbox[3] - bbox[1]);

  function drawPolygon(coordinates, dotted, labelSides = false) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    coordinates.forEach((coord, index) => {
      const x = (coord[0] - bbox[0]) * scaleX;
      const y = (bbox[3] - coord[1]) * scaleY;

      if (index === 0) {
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      } else {
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      }
    });
    ctx.closePath();
    if (dotted) {
      ctx.setLineDash([5, 5]);
    } else {
      ctx.setLineDash([]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();

    if (labelSides) {
      for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length - 1; i++) {
        const start = coordinates[i];
        const end = coordinates[i + 1];
        const mid = turf.midpoint(start, end);

        const midX = (mid.geometry.coordinates[0] - bbox[0]) * scaleX;
        const midY = (bbox[3] - mid.geometry.coordinates[1]) * scaleY;

        const length = turf.distance(start, end, {
          units: 'meters'
        }).toFixed(2);

        ctx.fillText(`${length}m`, midX, midY);
      }
    }
  }

  function getOffsetDistance(direction, offsets) {
    if (direction >= -45 && direction < 45) {
      return offsets.east;
    } else if (direction >= 45 && direction < 135) {
      return offsets.north;
    } else if (direction >= -135 && direction < -45) {
      return offsets.south;
    } else {
      return offsets.west;
    }
  }

  const features = geoJson.features;

  features.forEach(feature => {
    const coordinates = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
    drawPolygon(coordinates, false, true);

    const offsettedCoordinates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length - 1; i++) {
      const start = coordinates[i];
      const end = coordinates[(i + 1) % coordinates.length];

      const line = turf.lineString([start, end]);
      const direction = turf.bearing(start, end);

      const offsetDistance = getOffsetDistance(direction, offsets);
      const offsettedLine = turf.transformTranslate(line, offsetDistance, direction + 90, {
        units: 'centimeters'
      });

      offsettedCoordinates.push(offsettedLine.geometry.coordinates[0]);
      offsettedCoordinates.push(offsettedLine.geometry.coordinates[1]);
    }

    const uniqueOffsettedCoordinates = Array.from(new Set(offsettedCoordinates.map(JSON.stringify))).map(JSON.parse);
    uniqueOffsettedCoordinates.push(uniqueOffsettedCoordinates[0]); // Close the polygon

    const innerPolygon = turf.polygon([uniqueOffsettedCoordinates]);

    if (innerPolygon.geometry.type === 'Polygon') {
      const innerCoordinates = innerPolygon.geometry.coordinates[0];
      drawPolygon(innerCoordinates, true);
    }
  });
}

// Example usage
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const offsets = {
    north: 50, // in centimeters
    south: 50, // in centimeters
    east: 50, // in centimeters
    west: 50 // in centimeters
  };
  drawGeoJsonOnCanvas(exampleGeoJson, 'geoCanvas', offsets);
});
#geoCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Turf.js/6.5.0/turf.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="geoCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>




Reading "draw inner polygon where 4 sides (north,east,west,south) of the polygon will have different distances from outer polygon", does that mean that the offset differs depending on the bearing? Otherwise you could simply use a negative buffer: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/2434#issuecomment-2158285628

yes, offset depends on the bearing. I tried with offset being the same (single parameter for distance on all sides) and it works. But i need to implement a solution dependant on the bearing of the line segment. As you can see from the image the issue is with border cases when the line transitions from one bearing to another (edge cases).
